# Replace single with double quote inside pair of single quotes

Tags: python, regex

Here is what i am looking for:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"group":"stash-adt_ooms-dev","users":['stack', 'overflow']}' "url"
```

Result:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"group":"admin","users":["stack", "overflow"]}'
```

Need regex to replace words between `[]` from single quote to double quote.

Comment: In the output not only the `'`s are replaced by `"`, the values chaged, too. Do you want this?

Comment: no... I exactly need as mentioned in the result

Comment: Can you please help to maintain it same as result

Comment: Did any of the solutions below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the position of the open bracket and close brackets and then replace the `'` with `"`. You can do something like this:

```
_str = """curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"group":"stash-adt_ooms-dev","users":['stack', 'overflow']}' "url" """

start = _str.find ("[")
end = _str.find ("]")
buff = _str[start:end].replace ("'", "\"")
_str = _str[:start] + buff + _str[end:]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A regex approach using a lambda inside `re.sub` instead of a replacement string pattern:

```
import re
s = """curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"group":"stash-adt_ooms-dev","users":['stack', 'overflow']}' "url" """
res = re.sub(r"\[.*?]", lambda x: x.group().replace("'", '"'), s)
print(res)
# => curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"group":"stash-adt_ooms-dev","users":["stack", "overflow"]}' "url"
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/wHsH2M)

The `\[.*?]` regex matches a literal `[`, then matches zero or more characters other than a newline (add `flags=re.DOTALL` to the `re.sub` if you want to match the substring across multiple lines), as few as possible up to the first `]` that is also consumed.

The lambda takes the match data object `x`, and replaces the `'` with `"` only inside the match value `.group()`, i.e. inside *all the `[...]` substrings* in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "curl -X POST -H \"Content-type: application/json\" -d '{\"group\":\"stash-adt_ooms-dev\",\"users\":['stack', 'overflow']}' \"url\""

b = re.sub(r'\[\'(\w+)\', \'(\w+)\'\]',r'["\1", "\2"]' , a)
```

printing b will result in below:

```
'curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d \'{"group":"stash-adt_ooms-dev","users":["stack", "overflow"]}\' "url"'
```